# ValueError: Ran into a $end where it wasn't expected - RPLY Parsing (2)

Tags: python, parsing

[ValueError: Ran into a $end where it wasn't expected - RPLY Parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53790007/valueerror-ran-into-a-end-where-it-wasnt-expected-rply-parsing)

same error, please help me

```
[Token('IDENTIFIER', 'a'), Token('EQUAL', '='), Token('NUMBER', '1')]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 11, in <module>
    ast = parser.parse(tokens)
  File "/home/ybs1164/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rply/parser.py", line 60, in parse
    self.error_handler(lookahead)
  File "/home/ybs1164/Desktop/semilang/lib/parser_.py", line 26, in error_handler
    raise ValueError("Ran into a %s where it wasn't expected" % token.gettokentype())
ValueError: Ran into a $end where it wasn't expected
```

code is here -> https://github.com/ybs1164/semilang

python version is 3.8.10

Comment: You have exactly the same problem as the question you refer to. I answered it there and will mark this question as a duplicate.

Comment: For future reference: questions for StackOverflow should be self-contained. Code should be provided as plain text in your question -- not images; not pastebins;  and not as repository links. Images are hard to read and external links may not exist by the time this question is read again (or they may exist but not contain the same information). Please read [ask] for more useful information about how to ask a good question.

Comment: To get good code formatting, put three backticks (\```) before and after the code excerpt.

Comment: thanks everyone, i'll be careful next time.